How convert CSV table structure to JSON using Python?
Today I have a challenge at my school, it is convert a CSV file to a JSON file.
This CSV has a table structure (which means contains the information from an oracle table in this example). So i have to convert this CSV file into a hierarchical JSON.
My CSV example contain the next information:
TABLE_NAME,TIPO_CARGA,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE
CUENTAS,Full load,PERFIL,NVARCHAR2
CUENTAS,Full load,LLAMADA_INI,DATE
CUENTAS,Full load,LLAMADA_END,DATE
CUENTAS_PLAN,Delta,REGISTRO,NVARCHAR2
CUENTAS_PLAN,Delta,ULTIMA_VISITA,DATE
CUENTAS_PLAN,Delta,FECHA,DATE
CUENTAS_TACTICAS,Delta,CIUDAD,NVARCHAR2
CUENTAS_TACTICAS,Delta,SALIDA,NVARCHAR2
CUENTAS_TACTICAS,Delta,COMPLETADO,DATE
CUENTAS_MIEMBROS,Full load,NEGOCIO,NVARCHAR2
CUENTAS_MIEMBROS,Full load,CORE,NVARCHAR2
CUENTAS_MIEMBROS,Full load,DESC,NVARCHAR2

and I start with python using some libraries like pandas and also json, the next code is this:
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv("list_tablas_short.csv")

print(df.head())
thisisjson = df.to_json(orient='records')

print('CSV to JSON:\n', thisisjson)

thisisjson_dict = json.loads(thisisjson)
with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
json.dump(thisisjson_dict, json_file)

And the result is:
[
  {
    "TABLE_NAME;\"COLUMN_NAME\";\"DATA_TYPE\"": "CUENTAS;PERFIL;NVARCHAR2"
  },
  {
    "TABLE_NAME;\"COLUMN_NAME\";\"DATA_TYPE\"": "CUENTAS;LLAMADA_INI;DATE"
  },
  {...}
]

This is nto the way i'm looking for.
The idea is get something like this:
{
  "tablas": [
    {
      "nombre": "CUENTAS",
      "load_type": "Full load"
      "fields": [
        {
          "campo": "PERFIL",
          "tipo": "NVARCHAR2"
        },
        {
          "campo": "LLAMADA_INI",
          "tipo": "DATE"
        },
        {
          "campo": "LLAMADA_END",
          "tipo": "DATE"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "nombre": "CUENTAS_PLAN",
      "load_type": "Delta"
      "fields": [
        {
          "campo": "REGISTRO",
          "tipo": "NVARCHAR2"
        },
        {
          "campo": "ULTIMA_VISITA",
          "tipo": "DATE"
        },
        {
          "campo": "FECHA",
          "tipo": "DATE"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Can somebody help me with this?

Using a dictionary comprehension with groupby and to_dict:
import json

thisisjson_dict = {'tablas':
                   [{'nombre': n, 'load_type': l,
                     'fields': g.to_dict('records')}
                    for (n, l), g in df.rename(columns={'COLUMN_NAME':'campo',
                                                   'DATA_TYPE':'tipo'})
                                  .set_index(['TABLE_NAME', 'TIPO_CARGA'])
                                  .groupby(level=[0, 1])
                   ]
                  }

out = json.dumps(thisisjson_dict, indent=2)

Variant:
thisisjson_dict = {'tablas':
                   [{'nombre': n, 'load_type': l,
                     'fields': g.to_dict('records')}
                    for (n, l), g in df.rename(columns={'COLUMN_NAME':'campo',
                                                   'DATA_TYPE':'tipo'})
                                  .groupby(['TABLE_NAME', 'TIPO_CARGA'])
                                  [['campo', 'tipo']]
                   ]
                  }

out = json.dumps(thisisjson_dict, indent=2)

Output:
{
  "tablas": [
    {
      "nombre": "CUENTAS",
      "load_type": "Full load",
      "fields": [
        {
          "campo": "PERFIL",
          "tipo": "NVARCHAR2"
        },
        {
          "campo": "LLAMADA_INI",
          "tipo": "DATE"
        },
        {
          "campo": "LLAMADA_END",
          "tipo": "DATE"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "nombre": "CUENTAS_MIEMBROS",
      "load_type": "Full load",
      "fields": [
        {
          "campo": "NEGOCIO",
          "tipo": "NVARCHAR2"
        },
        {
          "campo": "CORE",
          "tipo": "NVARCHAR2"
        },
        {
          "campo": "DESC",
          "tipo": "NVARCHAR2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "nombre": "CUENTAS_PLAN",
      "load_type": "Delta",
      "fields": [
        {
          "campo": "REGISTRO",
          "tipo": "NVARCHAR2"
        },
        {
          "campo": "ULTIMA_VISITA",
          "tipo": "DATE"
        },
        {
          "campo": "FECHA",
          "tipo": "DATE"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "nombre": "CUENTAS_TACTICAS",
      "load_type": "Delta",
      "fields": [
        {
          "campo": "CIUDAD",
          "tipo": "NVARCHAR2"
        },
        {
          "campo": "SALIDA",
          "tipo": "NVARCHAR2"
        },
        {
          "campo": "COMPLETADO",
          "tipo": "DATE"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


using this code i have the next error : KeyError: "None of ['TABLE_NAME'] are in the columns"

@Julio you should have a TABLE_NAME column in your input df ("TABLE_NAME";"COLUMN_NAME";"DATA_TYPE"), please double check after you import the file. Otherwise you have to adapt it to the name of the column used for grouping

@Julio what is the output of print(df.columns) after your read_csv command?

my problem was the csv format, but now works. thanks

@Julio no worries ;)

if on my csv i receive a new column, and is part of table_name information. How i should add this on the result ? (I update my question) Regards

@Julio you have to group by several fields, see updated answer

Use list comprehension with DataFrame.rename and DataFrame.to_dict:
d = {'TABLE_NAME':'nombre',
     'TIPO_CARGA':'load_type',
     'COLUMN_NAME':'campo',
     'DATA_TYPE':'tipo'}

out = [{"nombre": n,'load_type': l, 'fields': g.to_dict(orient='records')}
       for (n,l), g in df.rename(columns=d)
                         .groupby(['nombre','load_type'])[['campo','tipo']]]


print (out)

[{
    'nombre': 'CUENTAS',
    'load_type': 'Full load',
    'fields': [{
        'campo': 'PERFIL',
        'tipo': 'NVARCHAR2'
    }, {
        'campo': 'LLAMADA_INI',
        'tipo': 'DATE'
    }, {
        'campo': 'LLAMADA_END',
        'tipo': 'DATE'
    }]
}, {
    'nombre': 'CUENTAS_MIEMBROS',
    'load_type': 'Full load',
    'fields': [{
        'campo': 'NEGOCIO',
        'tipo': 'NVARCHAR2'
    }, {
        'campo': 'CORE',
        'tipo': 'NVARCHAR2'
    }, {
        'campo': 'DESC',
        'tipo': 'NVARCHAR2'
    }]
}...

If need also tablas:
d = {'TABLE_NAME':'nombre',
     'TIPO_CARGA':'load_type',
     'COLUMN_NAME':'campo',
     'DATA_TYPE':'tipo'}

out = {"tablas": [{{"nombre":n,'load_type':l,'fields': g.to_dict(orient='records')}
       for (n,l), g in df.rename(columns=d)
                         .groupby(['nombre','load_type'])[['campo','tipo']]]}


print (out)


{
    'tablas': [{
        'nombre': 'CUENTAS',
        'load_type': 'Full load',
        'fields': [{
            'campo': 'PERFIL',
            'tipo': 'NVARCHAR2'
        }, {
            'campo': 'LLAMADA_INI',
            'tipo': 'DATE'
        }, {
            'campo': 'LLAMADA_END',
            'tipo': 'DATE'
        }]
    }, {
        'nombre': 'CUENTAS_MIEMBROS',
        'load_type': 'Full load',
        'fields': [{
            'campo': 'NEGOCIO',
            'tipo': 'NVARCHAR2'
        }, {
            'campo': 'CORE',
            'tipo': 'NVARCHAR2'
        }, {
            'campo': 'DESC',
            'tipo': 'NVARCHAR2'
        }]
    }...

For final json use:
j = json.dumps(out)

